# My app with GCM works for some but not for others

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I've written an Android chat progam that makes use of Google Cloud Messaging.

It works. People are able to chat.

However, some people are not because the app does not register with GCM from their device.

This could be due to:

- The user not having a Google account on their device.
- A firewall is preventing them from accessing ports: 5228, 5229, and 5230

It seems impossible to diagnose from my end since it works for some people but not others and all my devices work.

I'm looking for other ways to diagnose this problem. Any ideas will be appreciated.

I have added prompts to give the user a clue as to the problem, based on what GCMIntentService onError returns.

Comment: Did you find a solution how to work around these restrictions, thinking in particular on the blocked port range issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793477/make-gcm-work-on-all-networks