# Make GCM work on all networks

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

This is a follow up to this question.

[Which port and protocol does Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571576/which-port-and-protocol-does-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-use)

The issue here is that there are many WIFI networks out there which blocks the ports GCM use, and for me is sounds crazy that a push solution uses so often blocked ports, it makes our solution unreliable. We build apps for consumer market, not enterprises, so we can make reservations like "will only work on port range 5228-5230, make sure these ports are opened in your network".

I can't be the first one encountering this problem, was is the rational behind Google's use of these ports, and how can I work around it in a best practice way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, when you set a firewall in your network, it blocks all ports except default ports (used for general purposes such as HTTP, HTTPS, SMTP, etc...). If you to use other ports, you have to open them manually.

Google needed some ports for their service, and they chose 5228-5230. In a similar way, Apple chose 5223 for their push notifications. Both will be blocked in a normal firewall configuration, and have to be manually opened.

Since this issue is not unique to your applications (i.e. all the applications that use Google Cloud Messaging will be affected the same way by the GCM ports being blocked), there is no point worrying about it.